# How to use a fork of flutter.widgets in a flutter project?

Tags: flutter, github, git-fork

Found [this article](https://medium.com/flutter-community/how-to-modify-an-existing-pub-package-to-use-in-your-flutter-project-4e909452ee66), that seems like it would give sufficient instructions for using forked versions of many pub packages.

However, the package I want to fork ([scrollable_positioned_list](https://pub.dev/packages/scrollable_positioned_list)) is a part of a the flutter.widgets repository, which is not a package itself, but a collection of packages.

I've been able to fork and modify the package, my trouble is being able to use my fork in my project.

I've tried the obvious:

```yaml
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  scrollable_positioned_list: 
    git: 
      url: https://github.com/bendelonlee/flutter.widgets
```

This causes `flutter pub get` to fail with the error:

```
pub get failed (1; Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml" in https://github.com/bendelonlee/flutter.widgets 1f2935687390a9315c3336007a4eac00563365a4.)
```

Indeed, there is no pubspec.yaml in the root of that directory, though there is one nested in the package.

I've also tried using the url of the package inside the repository

```yaml
scrollable_positioned_list: 
    git: 
      url: https://github.com/bendelonlee/flutter.widgets/tree/master/packages/scrollable_positioned_list
```

This fails with an error complaining that the repository isn't found:

```
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/bendelonlee/flutter.widgets/tree/master/packages/scrollable_positioned_list/' not found
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The path argument should be added just as the [official docs](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#git-packages) state:

> Pub assumes that the package is in the root of the Git repository. To specify a different location in the repo, use the path argumen

In your specific cace this would be

```yaml
  scrollable_positioned_list:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/bendelonlee/flutter.widgets
      path: packages/scrollable_positioned_list
```